# loading q file gives error on window q session

Tags: kdb

I am using my windows to start q session. I am getting issue with file path while loading.
when I use system "l filename" works. but not with hsym.
Would anyone be able to kindly identify what errors I might be making?

```
q)system "l :E:/kdb/repository/stat.q"
q)key `.stat
``pctile`u12`skew`kurt`bm`gbm`iqr`ac`horner`ewma`cnorminv`tnorminv`norminv`oh.        
q)\l  `:E:/kdb/repository/stat.q
'nyi
q)p:hsym `:E:/kdb/repository/stat.q
q)p
`:E:/kdb/repository/stat.q
q)\l p
'p. OS reports: The system cannot find the file specified.
  [0]  (.Q.l)

 .Q )\
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `\l` does not expect a hsym, hence the error. If you want to load a file from hsym then convert to string and use the first method you have outlined.

```
system "l ",string 1_`:E:/kdb/repository/stat.q
```

Comment: Actually it should be `1_string`... because otherwise it will keep the colon in the string which is still incorrect